# How can I see if the same-origin-policy was applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

I am testing a website in Firefox 8.

I am using a `jQuery.post` call on a different domain.

In Firebug the result is just empty.

Can I see if this is due to the same origin policy? The error console is empty.

Comment: If it's calling a different domain it's 99% likely it's going to be the SOP. The other 1% is if your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you can.

But you can try to rule out other problems. Like your Ajax code is not working by making a normal Ajax request (not cross domain) to a static file. Also make a Ajax request to a static file on the target domain for the case where the server is down.